# pandas.read_sql Read uncommitted with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, isolation-level

I am trying to use the pandas function `pd.read_sql` to read records that have been created, added, and `flush`ed in a SQLAlchemy session, but not committed. So I want to create an object in a SQLAlchemy session and query it with pandas before calling `commit`. Using pandas 0.22.0 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.10.

I have tried setting the `isolation_level` on `create_engine`, and various other ways of setting the isolation level to 'READ UNCOMMITTED', but this does not seem to work. Minimal example below:

```
# Import packages 

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Set up an example ORM

Base = declarative_base()
class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String(255))

# Create a session and engine:

database='foobar'
user=''
password = ''
host = 'localhost'
port = '5432'

connection_string = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, encoding = 'utf8', convert_unicode = True,
    isolation_level='READ_UNCOMMITTED'
)
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
db = session()

# Set up the example record:

Record.__table__.create(bind=engine)
record = Record(foo='bar')
db.add(record)
db.flush()

# Attempt to query:

records = pd.read_sql('select * from records', db.get_bind())
assert records.empty
```

I am looking for a solution that will cause the above code to throw an `AssertionError` on the last line. `records.empty` currently evaluates to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And of course I figure it out as soon as I post here. For posterity: use `db.connection()` instead of `db.get_bind()`.

Comment: Curious, can you also use *engine* in *con* argument of `pd.read_sql` for uncommitted data?

Comment: @Parfait No, `db.get_bind()` is the same as `engine`. `db.get_bind() is engine` evaluates to True.

Comment: THANK YOU, I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: This solved our issue where we are using a scoped session from sqlalchemy where a configuration parameter needed to be set first).  Thanks!!!